# Disable Order Review Page when the id product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

how Disable Order Review Page when the id product  is 50710 
i use this code 
`remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );`

but i need disable order review only in id product : 50700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_order_review() {
    // Product id
    $product_id = 50700;

    // Generate cart id
    $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );

    // Is product in cart
    $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );

    // Product found
    if ( $in_cart ) {
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 1, 0 );
```